# Ajax post method to post data but getting alert message when refresh page

Tags: ajax, jquery

Im using below ajax to post

```
$('#myFormId').on('submit', function() {

    var form_data = {
        csrfsecurity: $("input[name=csrfsecurity]").val(),
        post_text: $('#post_text').val()    
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('/post_status'); ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        success: function(response){
            $(".home_user_feeds").html("markUpCreatedUsingResponseFromServer");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

when i post something and refresh page, browser shows below alert.

```
Confirm Form Resubmission

The page that you're looking for used information that you entred. Returning to that page might cause any action you took to be repeated.
```

how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try first preventing the default form event:

```
$('#myFormId').on('submit', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var form_data = {
        csrfsecurity: $("input[name=csrfsecurity]").val(),
        post_text: $('#post_text').val()    
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('/post_status'); ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        success: function(response){
            $(".home_user_feeds").html("markUpCreatedUsingResponseFromServer");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```